# Python ncclient returns RPCError: Unsupported capability :candidate when editing config of devnet ios xe

Tags: cisco, netconf, yang, ncclient

The xml conf:

```
    <config xmlns:xc="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0">  
       <interfaces xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:ietf-interfaces">
          <interface>
            <name>Loopback138</name>
            <description>TEST_SPSJM</description>
            <type xmlns:ianaift="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:iana-if-type">ianaift:softwareLoopback</type>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
          </interface>
      </interfaces>
    </config>
```

ncclient cmd:

```
nc_manager.edit_config(conf, default_operation="merge")
```

response:

```
RPCError: Unsupported capability :candidate
```

while getting interfaces with the ietf-interfaces yang works fine.

Comment: `while getting interfaces with the ietf-interfaces yang works fine`; which NETCONF operation are you using to retrieve this data (get, get-config, get-data) and which parameters do you supply to it (if any)?

Comment: Also, what is your question?

Comment: get_config to get the config data, edit_config to set the config on the device.

Comment: You should check if `nc_manager.edit_config(...)` supports a way to supply the target datastore parameter to the resulting `edit-config` RPC. Perhaps `candidate` is the default value for this argument. You should try with `running` instead. This API you are using seems to think your device does not support the `candidate` datastore.